# How to setup SonarQube 6 with Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, configuration, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

- I’ve experimented with SonarQube 6.0 using the H2 default database
  and now I wanted to see how we can configure it with oracle 11
  database.
- I’ve tried the following [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server) but it is not clear what
  tables (schema) would be created on oracle DB. Does it need its own
  separate DB or I can connect it to our own existing DB ? If the
  latter one is right and SonarQube automatically creates the tables, i
  wanted to make sure it won’t drop any tables or data (for
  e.g if they have a script that would drop tables and recreate them.
- I know this is unlikely to happen but we had one plugin in the past
  that did something like that and I wanted to be cautious ).

I appericiate if you can guide me with the steps. I’ve already configured the sonar.properties file to point to our current DB.

```
sonar.jdbc.username=bdr
sonar.jdbc.password=dev1pass
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev3.our.domain.com:1522:dev3
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [stated in the documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server), you need to

> Create an empty schema and a sonarqube user. Grant this sonarqube user
>   permissions to create, update and delete objects for this schema.

Given that schema and the proper permissions to it, SonarQube will indeed create its own tables, indexes, &etc. And since you're going to carefully restrict the sonarqube user's permissions to only the sonarqube schema, there should be no question of interfering with existing tables or data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did as requested. I've one more issue though. The documentaiton recommends UTF-8 and English as charset and language respectively. However, our DB has WE8ISO8859P1 and language as "American". I don't have the authority to change those values but is there a work around ?

Comment: I found the following error regarding the char set. xception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Oracle must be have UTF8 charset and BINARY sort. NLS_CHARACTERSET is WE8ISO8859P1 and NLS_SORT is BINARY.

So SonarQube is not compatible unless the database has char set UTF8 ? At this time, I don't think we would be able to change to UTF 8. Please advice the best solutions other than creating a new DB with UTF 8 schema. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the language "English" is not required.

Answer (score 1):

For your information, WE8ISO8859P1 is a single byte character set. It has 255 characters. UTF-8 uses 1-4 bytes per character.

Comment: i.e It is a MUST to have char set to UTF-8 ? I don't think changing char set for the entire DB might not happen soon. I'm looking for alternative solutions. Otherwise, we might be forced to use the H2 internal DB available from SonarQube DB.